# Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command when trying to download Jupyter Notebook as PDF

Tags: jupyter-notebook, xelatex

I have spent the last few hours trying to figure out how to download my Jupyter Notebook as a pdf. I have downloaded MiKTeX as well as reinstalled anaconda. Full Error below

500 : Internal Server Error
The error was:
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command:
Making rsfs10.tfm from "C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/rsfs\rsfs10.mf"...
Running miktex-mf.exe...
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit)

(C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/rsfs\rsfs

10.mf

(C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/cm\cmbase

.mf)

(C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/rsfs\scri

pt.mf

(C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/rsfs\scri

ptu.mf [65] [66] [67] [68] [69] [70] [71] [72] [73] [74] [75] [76] [77]

[78] [79] [80] [81] [82] [83] [84] [85] [86] [87] [88] [89] [90] [127]) ) )

Font metrics written on rsfs10.tfm.

Output written on rsfs10.600gf (27 characters, 9120 bytes).

Transcript written on rsfs10.log.

Installing C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/tfm/public/rsfs\rsfs10.tfm...
Making rsfs5.tfm from "C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/rsfs\rsfs5.mf"...
Running miktex-mf.exe...
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit)

(C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/rsfs\rsfs

5.mf

(C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/cm\cmbase

.mf)

(C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/rsfs\scri

pt.mf

(C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/rsfs\scri

ptu.mf [65] [66] [67] [68] [69] [70] [71] [72] [73] [74] [75] [76] [77]

[78] [79] [80] [81] [82] [83] [84] [85] [86] [87] [88] [89] [90] [127]) ) )

Font metrics written on rsfs5.tfm.

Output written on rsfs5.600gf (27 characters, 4704 bytes).

Transcript written on rsfs5.log.

Installing C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/tfm/public/rsfs\rsfs5.tfm...
notebook.tex:384:
notebook.tex:387:

Answer (score 8):

Solved my problem!

Within the LaTeX I had in my Jupyter notebook, I was using `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` in order to have some equations I made line up nicely with their equal signs all stacked. Turns out for some reason this was causing all my errors.

I simply replaced `{align}` with `{split}` (ie. using `\begin{split}` and `\end{split}`) from `amsmath`. Equations look the same as before, and it creates a perfect pdf.

Comment: Can you detail what you did?

Answer (score 3):

I had effectively the same error, so I will add a bit of generality to [zεԺ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12877395/z%CE%B5%D4%BA)’s advice.

These errors appear to be created due to LaTeX processing errors. Note, however, that the errors were shown neither in the jupyter notebook nor in the LaTeX-typeset pdf, but they did cause a failure during the `nbconvert` processing (despite finding the correct LaTeX, eg. xelatex, engine).

I would advise, therefore to check your LaTeX code carefully based on the errors `nbconvert` sends to `stdout`. For me, I had to change the following math-mode obstacles for the `nbconvert` processing to flow and complete smoothly:

- `$1` → `$ 1` — (added a space; suspected conflict with shell processing)
- `$ \\Delta [...]` → `$\\Delta [...]` — (removed a space; suspected conflict with shell processing)

Comment: I also had to get rid of empty spaces in between, so `$ 1` to `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving the same 500 Internal Server Error:

> 500 : Internal Server Error
> The error was:
> nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
> Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command:

But without accompanying command. After updating all dependencies, I eventually solved it by removing every jupyter cell I had set to "Raw NBConvert."

Answer (score 0):

I tried various solutions available, nothing worked.

```
pip install --upgrade --user nbconvert
```

The above solved it for me, make sure to update `MikTeX` first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on windows and I had a similar message:

> nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
>
> Failed to run "xelatex notebook.tex -quiet" command:

I realized I had clicked on a checkbox which hid package installation dialog boxes. I fixed it by:

1. Opening MikeTeX Console
2. Going to Settings
3. Under "Package installation" I chose for the packages to be installed on the fly by choosing "Always".

This fixed my issue.